# Extracting data from POSIXct

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I created from a `.CVS` file. I used POSIXct to convert the date information from fctr format to dttm format. I am attempting to create columns for the day, month, and year from the POSIXct column.

```
trial <- fourteen %>%
   mutate(test = as.POSIXct(V3, format="%m/%d/%y. %H:%M %p.")) %>%
   mutate(trial, date = ymd_hm(test), day = day(date), 
   month = month(date), year = year(date))
   View(trial)
```

I keep on getting the error message

> Error: wrong result size (9), expected 6301 or 1

and I cannot find a solution to this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your `mutate(trial, ...` is not clear.  If 'trial' is already a column in the dataset, why you need to specify it without transforming it.

Comment: When I take out trial I get this error message "All formats failed to parse. No formats found."

Comment: that means the format your showed is not the correct one.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the error, can you please describe contents of the object "fourteen". I don't know how others are giving recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. I did this by changing date = ymd_hm to ymd_hms and that worked for my purposes.